# Restrict Google Custom Search with a logical AND?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I created a Google CSE and I want it to add to my query `"AND (apples OR BANANAS)"`.

Besides that, is there a way to retrieve specific info from result pages?

Is this possible, if yes how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, I think you would have to manually add "AND (apples OR BANANAS)" to each query string.

For the second part, I"m not sure quite what you mean by 'specific info', but if you want extended info, take a look at the pageMap information that is returned as part of each Result - that often gives useful additional info.  For anything beyond what is in the list of results, you would need to retrieve and parse the corresponding page yourself.

Comment: can you please expand more about the page map part, is it something that is returned along with the results? To make sure we're on the same page, I have no control on those websites I want to search, and cannot adapt them to match the search engines requirements.

Comment: Yes, the pageMap is returned along with the results.  It is optional meta-data for the website, which the website provides to Google.  You will need to find out whether Google has pageMap info the sites you are interested in.  Look at Custom Search API in cloud console and you will find that there is a web page for doing test searches and it will show you the results and you can see what is included for your sites.